# Update command to update single row in Excel using OLEdb and dataaset. (C#)

Tags: c#, oledb

I am importing data from Excel an spreadsheet. I am only using OLEDB to read. But i am having trouble saving the result back to the original file. Below is my code so far.

```
string ExcelConnectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Mode=ReadWrite;" +
        "Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1\";",
        Server.MapPath("./Uploads/" + excelName));
    try
    {
        OleDbDataAdapter ExcelDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$A8:AZ67]", ExcelConnectionString);
        DataSet objDataSet = new DataSet();
        ExcelDataAdapter.Fill(objDataSet, "ExcelTable");
        for (int i = 0; i < objDataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++ )
        {
            Slab slb = new Slab();
            slb.ReceiveDate = objDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i].Field<DateTime>(0);
            slb.VesselName = objDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i].Field<string>(1);
            slb.Lot = Convert.ToInt16(objDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i].Field<double>(2));
            slb.SlabSource = objDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i].Field<string>(3);
            slb.CertificateNumber = objDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i].Field<string>(4);

            //I think the next two lines do the same thing.
            objDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i][4] = "message here";
            objDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i].SetField<string>(51, "message here");
            ExcelDataAdapter.Update(objDataSet, "ExcelTable");
                  .............
        }
```

I get the following error :

> Update requires a valid UpdateCommand when passed DataRow collection with modified rows.

The documentation shows update commands syntax similar to :

> UPDATE table SET fieldID = 1, Description = 'nice' WHERE RegionID = 1
>   But that wont work for me, i need to update the current row in the for loop.

Any help apprecaited,
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow.

I mean... wow.

I don't think that particular method of self-flagellation is supported past XP.

I'd highly suggest you drop OLEDB and pick up one of the many API's for dealing with excel files.  You can find a bunch of them here:  http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?projectSearchText=excel

I've used a couple and they worked pretty damn good.  Alernatively, check out the [OpenXML sdk](http://blogs.msdn.com/excel/archive/2008/11/25/using-the-open-xml-sdk-to-work-with-excel-files.aspx) if you plan on just supporting Office 2007+.

Comment: What is self-flagellation ?
I am using OLEDB because i don't need to install office on the server.
OLEDB should work. I will update my question, i have made some progress.

Comment: whipping one's self ... OLEdb means i am whipping myself? Is it really that hard ?

Comment: Compared to framework-based methods of dealing with documents, definitely.  Please note--you're struggling to just save your changes to disk, are you not?  OLEDB is pretty old technology; things have improved since it has come around.  And you don't need to install office to use any of the things I mentioned in my answer.  Really, download a couple and take them for a spin.  You'll be much happier.